# If $_POST variable is not 3 numbers long

Tags: php

I would like to get a person's weight, who is over 18 years old so very likely to be 100 pounds plus, so I want to check if the $_POST variable for the weight entered is 3 digits only. I have a form where the user enters their weight...

```
if (!is_numeric($weight)) {
    echo "You did not enter a numeric weight.";
    die;
}
```

Using the above to make sure it's numeric... but also want to verify the number is 3 digits.

Thank you

Comment: What is wrong with checking whether it is <1000?

Comment: And $age < 125 .. (for example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
is_numeric($weight) && ($weight > 99) && ($weight < 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't see it this way from the start.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with age.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ please read the question again before down voting

Comment: It still doesn't have anything to do with age. You should check to see if the weight is numeric before assigning it to a variable though to have good form.